# Does a UK entry ban affect travel to other countries?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

Ireland? EU/Schengen party states? Asian and South American countries?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UK is part of the [Five Countries Conference group](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/biometric-data-sharing-fingerprint-matching-process-and-diagram), which agreed to share information about visa applications and other immigration intelligence between themselves - the other members of this group are Canada, the US, New Zealand and Australia.  It is highly likely that a ban in the UK would affect applications to these countries.

The UK also has access to and informs the [Schengen Information System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en), so there is data sharing occurring there - however, it is noted that as the UK is not a full member it cannot issue SIS alerts but there is no information on whether UK refusals or immigration issues are available to SIS users.  It is possible but not certain that a ban in the UK would affect Schengen applications of travel.

The UK and Ireland are part of the [Common Travel Area](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_abroad/freedom_of_movement_within_the_eu/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html), which means both countries closely cooperate and share data between themselves - a refusal or ban in either country can certainly affect applications to the other country, due to the common travel area movement rules. It is highly likely that a ban in the UK would affect applications or travel to Ireland.

Comment: Moo, if I may ask, what is the principal source of your apparently extensive knowledge on these topics?

Comment: I must say that this is an excellently helpful and informative answer. Thanks

Comment: The UK does not participate in SIS except for the law enforcement aspects, which means alerts for wanted criminals. It *is* certain that a UK ban would not appear in SIS, because that is not a criminal matter.

Comment: @JosephP. I trained to be a magistrate in a part of the UK which sees a lot of immigration related issues - some of them ended up infront of me (the vast majority of which were passed up the chain).  I also take a lot of interest in what my home country does with regard to personal data privacy and campaign against it where I think it makes sense to.

Comment: @MJeffryes: as far as the UK is concerned, is overstaying not technically a criminal offense?

Comment: @Joseph P. It is almost never prosecuted, because this leads to the overstayer spending more time in the UK to attend trial, and legal processes have routes of appeal which UKVI tends to dislike.

Comment: Thank you @Moo. Having similar interests, I must say that that is quite admirable. As for your attitude toward me, I cannot get into too much detail, but would like to say on my behalf that my life's course has taken a very unusual course due to many events well beyond my control. Objectively, these events comprise serious human rights violations, and the true reason that I have been in the UK has pertained to seeking recognition of these things and I have in actual truth spent much of that last three years trying to figure out how to seek support in applying for asylum. I have been exploited

Comment: @JosephP. thats worthy of a separate question, but yes it is a criminal matter.  However, as MJeffryes says its rarely taken to trial as UKVI have ample legal authority to remove persons anyway.

Comment: eg - There are three ways of dealing with illegal entrants: 1. administratively, by the Immigration Authorities i.e. Immigration Enforcement officers or the Home Office, 2. diversion by way of a Foreign National Offender Conditional Caution (FNOCC), 3. by way of criminal proceedings. https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/immigration

Comment: @JosephP. unless you can make a case as a US citizen against the US government regarding those human rights abuses, an asylum request in the UK would be likely to fail imho.

Comment: I don't know how much is innocuous to disclose to you, and don't want you to alert the h.o. to the generic details of my case so that they might look out for me in case you have some vigilante inclinations, but I would appreciate it if you would adjust your attitude towards me and accept on the benefit of the doubt that there have been extenuating circumstances tying my hands. In other words if your attitude essentially amounts to "well you should have thought of all this before you wilfully decided to break the law," well, I didn't choose to.

Comment: I broke the law under conditions of extreme pressure and timidation. The effects of which, yes, involve lessening your capacity to maintain awareness of time and legal requirements.

Comment: I began to write more but decided against including too much sensitive details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110324/discussion-between-joseph-p-and-moo).

Comment: @JosephP. on weekdays I have to work my day job... its now nearly 10pm where I am right now, and Ive had a packed day.  SE isnt a paid job for me, its relaxation - so I will get round to answering when Im in the right frame of mind.

Comment: @Moo thanks for explaining this. I was just asking because I saw you active on other threads, so I was wondering if you were intending to answer these more personal notes at all. I would appreciate seeing what you have to say in response to them, for what that is worth. Thanks for your informations this far.

Answer (score 9):

Many countries will **ask** in their visa forms if visa or entries to a third country have ever been denied.

Even if there is no automatic data sharing it is a bad idea to lie on a visa form. If you tell the truth, the visa may be denied because of the bad travel history, or it may be granted if the rest of the application looks good. If you lie and that gets caught, the visa will be denied and there may be the next ban.

Comment: and you can be banned for a long time. And then on your next application to a different country you'll have to say "I was banned for lying on a visa application"...