# UK Entry Denied or Refused

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, australia, denial-of-entry

I recently completed my studies in the UK and went on holiday to Europe. During this time, the Home Office emailed me, stating that I am eligible for a Post-Study Visa.

However, they also mentioned that if I am outside the UK, I should apply for another visa to re-enter because Post-Study Visa eligibility applies only if you are inside the UK. To be honest, I didn't read the entire email.

When I returned to the UK, border authorities stopped me and issued a 7-day removal notice. I informed them that I plan to voluntarily leave the UK within 7 days, which I did. However, I currently hold an Australia visa.

Would Australian immigration question me or prevent me from entering?

Comment: If your passport was stamped to indicate the entry refusal, you can most likely expect to be questioned about it by Australian border officials.

Comment: Should i make new passport and lose both of my passport new and old but Australia issue visa on my old passport which is going to expire in end of Oct 2023.

Comment: **No**, absolutely not, that is *a very bad idea*. Leaving aside the biometric links between you and your passports, the UK and Australia are part of the [‘Five eyes group’](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158170/does-a-uk-entry-ban-affect-travel-to-other-countries), the extent of immigration data-sharing between the countries isn’t publicised but if you were discovered you would almost certainly be banned. If you’re asked about previous immigration history, tell the truth and show them the Post Study visa email from UK

Comment: Is it recommended that I bring my stamped passport and be truthful when going through border clearance?

Comment: "To be honest, I didn't read the entire email." Well there's the root of the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Turning comments into an answer:

- If your passport was stamped to indicate the UK entry refusal, you can most likely expect to be questioned about it by Australian border officials
- If you’re asked about previous immigration history on arrival at Australian border clearance, tell the truth and show them the Post Study visa email from UK as evidence. Have the 7-day removal notice with you, in case you are asked for it.
- Do *not* attempt to try to hide this unfortunate situation by eg ‘losing’ your passport. Leaving aside the biometric links between you and your passports, the UK and Australia are part of the [‘Five eyes group’](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158170/does-a-uk-entry-ban-affect-travel-to-other-countries), the full extent of immigration data-sharing between the countries isn’t publicised but if such a deception attempt was discovered you would almost certainly be banned.

Note: this answer assumes you still meet the eligibility criteria for your Australian visa, and can prove it, if required.